# Suppressing some crossbars when drawing error bars with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add an if else statement within the mapping statement within `geom_errorbar()` that removes the lower error bar if it fulfills a certain criteria. See the following toy dataset  and graph

```
df <- data.frame(change = rep(c("increased", "reduced", "same"), 2),
                 group = rep(c("0", "1"), each = 3),
                 freq = c(0, 17, 21, 1, 27, 9),
                 perc = c(0, 44.73, 55.26, 2.70, 72.97, 24.32),
                 se = c(NaN, 12.06, 10.85, 16.22, 8.54, 14.30))

polytPlot <- ggplot(dfT, aes(y = perc, x = change, fill = Group)) +
                    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
                    scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty) + 
                    ylab("% of group total") +
                    xlab("Change") +
                    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ifelse(perc-se < 0, 0, perc-se), ymax = perc+se), position = position_dodge(.9), width = .1)
polytPlot
```

Note that the `ifelse()` statement in the `ymin` argument of `geom_errorbar` in the above example *does* work, reducing the lower error bar to zero, but it still displays the horizontal portion of the error bar. How do I suppress this, so only the upper error-bar appears? I tried entering `NULL` instead of 0 in my conditional `ifelse()` statement but got an error message. Perhaps a conditional argument to `width =`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to remove the horizontal crossbars altogether:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = perc, x = change, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty) + 
  ylab("% of group total") +
  xlab("Change") +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ifelse(perc-se < 0, 0, perc-se), ymax = perc+se), position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

If you really want the crossbars, however, you can draw them separately using `geom_segment()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = perc, x = change, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty, limits = c(0, 85)) + 
  ylab("% of group total") +
  xlab("Change") +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ifelse(perc-se < 0, 0, perc-se), ymax = perc+se), position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(change) + .45*(as.numeric(group)-1.5) - .05,
                   xend = as.numeric(change) + .45*(as.numeric(group)-1.5) + .05,
                   y = perc + se, yend = perc + se)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(change) + .45*(as.numeric(group)-1.5) - .05,
                   xend = as.numeric(change) + .45*(as.numeric(group)-1.5) + .05,
                   y = perc - se, yend = perc - se))
```

[image]

Note that the missing segment is removed by the `limits` statement I added to `scale_y_continuous()`.

Comment: Thank you @ Claus Wilke, both good solutions. I gather there is no simple way to remove the horizontal bars. Oh well. I will probably go to prism for the publication graphs anyway.

Comment: It's two additional geoms. Seems fairly straightforward to me. Note that there isn't much in terms of magic numbers. 0.45 is simply 0.9/2, and everything else would carry over to whatever production dataset you have.

Comment: Sorry @Claus Wilke. I was not maligning your solution at all, merely commenting on the functionality in ggplot. There are so many possible permutations of a graph that it is impossible for Hadley to have anticipated them all.

Comment: If you think this is a common problem, then it might be worth it to write a geom that has separate parameters for the top and bottom crossbar width. That would be quite straightforward with the new ggplot2 extension framework.